# Meaning of "from whose known good sense he fully expected to have just such" from "Persuasion" by Jane Austen

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, sentence-structure

I don't understand the structure of the **bold** part of the sentence below. It's from [*Persuasion*](https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/a/austen/jane/a93p/chap2.html) by Jane Austen.

> Mr Shepherd, a civil, cautious lawyer, who, whatever might be his hold
>   or his views on Sir Walter, would rather have the disagreeable
>   prompted by anybody else, excused himself from offering the slightest
>   hint, and only begged leave to recommend an implicit reference to the
>   excellent judgement of Lady Russell, **from whose known good sense he
>   fully expected to have just such resolute measures advised as he meant
>   to see finally adopted.**

Might I have an explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: This is a difficult passage. Most native speakers would be unable to parse it.

Comment: The unusual thing about the construction there is that we encounter **from** not **by**, and thus we have the *source*  of the advice (her good sense) rather than the advisor herself in agent position.

Comment: Let's suppose Lady Russell is a fashion consultant who helps her clients choose items from their vast wardrobes, and Mr Shepherd wants Sir Walter to dress appropriately: "....from whose good fashion sense he fully expected to have such apparel suggested as he meant to see finally worn."

Answer (score 4):

OK, let's break it down.  "...from whose known good sense he fully expected to have just such resolute measures advised as he meant to see finally adopted"

The meaning overall is that the protagonist is expecting Lady Russell to speak out and recommend exactly what he wanted to do anyway.

"he ... expected to have just such resolute measures advised" - he expected that exactly those sort of actions would be advised.

"such ... measures as he meant to see ... adopted" - those actions which he wants to happen.  Here 'meant' is being used in an older sense than you generally encounter it these days.  It is used in the sense of "I mean to do x!" to show that your intention is to do x.

Comment: Does the sentence "from whose known good sense he fully expected to have just such resolute measures advised" mean "He fully expected to have just such resolute measures advised from the known good sense of the excellent judgement of Lady Russell"?

Comment: the **good sense** is an attribute of Lady Russell herself. **Whose** good sense; **whose** implies an attribute of a person.  He recommends reference to the judgement of Lady Russell. He has faith in the good sense of Lady Russell .

Comment: @djna    Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.